# I keep getting this error: Not allowed to load local resource

Tags: javascript, html, file, local

I have created my own local media server with html and I'm trying to access these files that are located on a different drive than to that of the website but it keeps outputting that same error:

> Not allowed to load local resource

I have tried creating an alias to give access to the files that way as it worked for me before but it isn't working now. I'm using ampps to host the local server of an old desktop.

```
<div id="select_box">
  <div id="box1" onclick="VidFileTree('../../Videos/')"><p id="box1_txt" >Page 1</p></div>
  <div id="box2" onclick="VidFileTree('E:/Videos1/')"><p id="box2_txt" >Page 2</p></div>
</div>
```

Comment: try like this

file:///E:/Videos1/

Comment: like anything else you load into a web page, it must be loaded via a HTTP request. If those files are not accessible via the machine's webserver, then you'll need to configure it so that they are. Otherwise they won't be accessible. You can't load things via a file path for security reasons - imagine if someone else was viewing this page on _their_ machine...it would try to load something from their hard disk...pretty blatant breach of privacy wouldn't you think? Not to mention you'd have no way of knowing if such a file even existed. So overall, what you're doing doesn't make any sense :-)

Comment: Ok so  how do I make it so that the drive is accessible via the web server and the "file:///" method didn't seem to work.

Comment: Depends what webserver you're using (e.g. IIS or Apache are the most common ones). You can easily look up the instructions for the relevant product

Comment: It's an Apache web server so what would I search

Comment: Good grief. how about "apache add folder" to start with???